# Why does my dynamically allocated array not work?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, gcc, mingw

I have recently moved from Linux to Windows 10 for my OpenGL C++ projects, and the first time I do something with arrays on Windows, they suddenly don't seem to work anymore. Every time I try to create an array from a non-const variable that represents a size, the execution of the program does nothing (meaning no output to the console, but also no error message). It compiles fine. To understand what I mean, look at this code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int s = 10;
    float* array = new float[s];
    std::cout << *array;
    delete[] array;

    return 0;
}
```

It is perfectly legit, but when compiling it with MinGW on Windows and then running it, nothing happens. Yet, using the GCC compiler on Linux writes a 0 to the console, which is perfectly fine and logical, indicating that it is not the code that is flawed. Do you know what could cause this problem? It is really on Windows that I have encountered this behaviour for the first time. Both compilation commands are straight-forward:

```
g++ array-test.cpp -o array-test
```

Note that making s a const int fixes the issue, but I do want my arrays to be **dynamically** allocated, from user input.

I am using a relatively unspectacular text editor (Notepad++) and compile in the Windows PowerShell with MinGW. The supplied code replicates the behaviour on my machine, but I cannot guarantee that it will do so on others as well. Even example code from the internet creating an array with a non-const variable as size will not run.

Comment: You allocate `s` number of ***uninitialized*** `float` values. You output the first (`*array` is equal to `array[0]`) of those uninitialized values, which leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Try: `float* array = new float[s]{};`

Comment: As pointed out by @Someprogrammerdude, uninitialized values don't have a defined behaviour, so if you really want to know if the array works, you should try to fill it first with some values

Comment: And unless this is for an assignment or exercise of some kind, where you're forced to use pointers and `new[]`, please always use `std::vector` instead of explicit "dynamic arrays". Using `std::vector` would also solve your problem, since if you initialize a vector of a specific size, all elements in it will be default-initialized (which for `float` values means `0.0f`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you for your quick reply, but this and my question have little to do with each other. Doing array[0] = 0.5f; still gives me no output on Windows, but Linux writes 0.5 to the console.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude For example, new float[10]; **gives** output on Windows / MinGW, but new float[s]; doesn't.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code statement by statement in a debugger? And is the code you show in the question enough to replicate the behavior in your environment? What *is* your environment? Are you using an IDE? Which one? What compiler (and version of it) are you using? Please [edit] your question to include as many details as possible.

Comment: Your code has undefined behaviour but you say it also breaks when you fix that. Could you edit your code to be something that you think should not have undefined behaviour so that we can give a sensible answer please?

Comment: Try adding `<< endl` to your `cout` line.

Comment: Output must, eventually, end with a newline. So: `std::cout << *array << ‘\n’:`. Without the newline the behavior is undefined.

Comment: _Whether the last line requires a terminating new-line character is implementation-deﬁned._